# How to use script variable in scriplet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Can anyone help me to get the value from name variable and store it in name_val?

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       function dropdelete(ev)
        {
            var name=document.getElementById("user"+stringToArray[1]).value;
        }
   <% String name_val ; %>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: How this question got 3 upvotes already is kind of mind boggling. It has disturbing implications about the number of web programmers that don't know how their tools work.

Comment: Haha..The person who ask this question  may be a very luck. Getting more and more up votes for this kind of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant directly get it, however of course if the value was pre-populated by the server side and you were to store the value of `name_val` in a hidden field or other DOM element, then you could use javscript or jquery to access it.

```
<input type="hidden" id="nameValue" value=${nameValue}>
```

and then access it as

```
document.getElementById("nameValue").value;
```

**Update**

To add a bit of context to my answer, I am assuming that the above JSP is being called (Redirected) from a controlling servlet.

This servlet could set a request parameter which is sent to the JSP page

The JSP page could read the request parameter and store it in a hidden field

When the page has loaded, Javascript or Jquery could read the value from the hidden field and use it.

I guess this is what the OP is wanting to do, that is, use the value, not just store it in a variable.

Comment: @Downvoter - don't be scared - tell me why, and then I add value to this site.

Comment: You actually have 5 down voters, mostly because your answer does not make much sense, for reasons that I'm not sure would fit in one comment. The fact that the OP marked your answer as correct suggests that you two may be communicating in code, or possibly share a psychic bond. I cannot explain it, but it is very twilight zone.

Comment: I believe the OP was trying to go the other way; `name_val = name`, where `name` is content that is dynamically entered by the user in an element on the page, not static content. Is your answer meant to suggest an AJAX style approach where the dynamic client content is sent, in the background, to the server by the current page for further processing? If so, javaBeginner's answer is a good example of a clear explanation of that technique.

Comment: Hmm, if the OP really did want to go the other, then it does show a lack of understanding about the flow of things.  My answer is not suppose to suggest anything in the way of how the OP will use the value.  Maybe Ajax, maybe further DOM processing, maybe modify the value and POST it to a servlet - with the lack of this in the question, who knows?

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense and I have removed my particular downvote.

Comment: Cheers, and thank you for spending the time to explain why you downvoted - it helps everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. That doesn't make any sense. Your `name_val` declaration is in your server-side JSP script. It is executed on the server when the page is being generated and sent to the client. This happens long before, and independently of, the client's execution of the Javascript on your page.

By the time the page is sent to the client, your JSP code has run and is finished. That's how JSP works.

You will have to rethink your design a bit. You could move relevant logic into client-side Javascript, or submit data back to the server for processing (AJAX style or in a new request e.g. via a form, or GET parameter in a redirect), or something, but in any case, you'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 3):

javascript is a client side and jsp is a server side.So you **can not store** like this way

String name_val =document.getElementById("user"+stringToArray[1]).value;

try ajax in the following way

```
var name=document.getElementById("user"+stringToArray[1]).value;
$.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "store.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                   data: { name: name},
                   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                       alert(data);                  
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR){
                       alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                   }
               });
```

now in store.jsp

```
<%String name_val =request.getparameter("name");%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get JavaScript value and store into Java variable because JavaScript is executed at client side while the Java variable execute at server side. In this case the server side execute first and followed by the client side

Alternatively, You may use form to store the value in the hidden field and make use back via foorm submission.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=xxx;
```